# Menú de opciones con array

Tags: java, array, string

Buenas tengo un problema y es que no se como hacer la opción de suprimir (eliminar) y la opción de ordenar para mi `array` de `String`. Me gustaría que me pudierais ayudar a acabar esas 2 opciones.

Aquí os adjunto el lo que tengo hecho del programa.

```
package menu;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class m03_menu {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        //conta el numero d'el·lements que hi ha a la llista
        int select = -1;
        //limitar el array
        int pos,num_elements = 15;
        int elem = 14;
        //ELEMENT: es el nom que afegirem
        String element;
        String alum[] = new String[num_elements];
        //afegim als alumnes manualment
        alum[0] = "Florian";
        alum[1] = "Sebastian";
        alum[2] = "Enric";
        //indiquem amb el 3 els alumes que hem afegit manulament

        while (select != 0) {
            System.out.println("Opcions a ellegir: \n1.- Inserir" +
                        "\n2.- Localitzar i Recuperar\n" +
                        "3.- Suprimir\n" +
                        "4.- Anular\n" +
                        "5.- Imprimir\n" +
                        "6.- Ordenar\n");
            select = sc.nextInt();
            switch(select) {
```

Debajo del `switch` están los `case` con cada opción y los que me faltan por finalizar son la opción 3 y la opción 6.

---

```
            Arrays.sort(alum);
            for(int j = 0;j < alum.length-1;j++) {
                System.out.println(alum[j]);
                 break;
```

Comment: Y qué es lo que quieres hacer en esas dos opciones? Suprimir qué?

Comment: con esas dos opciones me gustaría eliminar un objeto de dentro del array y con la opción de ordenar me gustaría ordenar los objetos del array por orden alfabético al ser posible.

Comment: Y qué has intentado? Ordenar podría ser más complicado, dependiendo de cómo quieras implementarlo. Eliminar es más fácil. Pedir al usuario que introduzca la cadena a eliminar, y recorrer el array de Strings comparando hasta encontrarlo. Inténtalo y sube lo que no te funcione.

Comment: vale en el caso de ordenar he visto que me lo piden usando el método de burbuja o el sort he intentado hacerlo en el método de burbuja y esto es lo que tengo pero no funciona.

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y coloca el código en la pregunta, no en la respuesta. En caso de no poder editar, vale más que borres la pregunta y crees una nueva con todo escrito. Piensa que la resolución de tu pregunta quedará aquí para consulta, para usuarios a los que les pase lo mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Voy a suponer que esto es un ejercicio que te han puesto en los estudios que estas cursando, y como muchos pensaran considero que la respuesta no deberíamos dártela directamente pero si podemos guiarte.

**Para Suprimir**

Para suprimir un valor de un vector requieres disponer de la posición y la longitud del vector.
Entonces empezamos a recorrer el vector desde el indice que nos interesa y machacamos el valor indicando que el valor de vector[indice] es vector[indice +1] así sucesivamente finalmente pondremos el ultimo indice del vector a null. vector[indice] = null

**Ordenación por burbuja**

Para ordenado de Strings tenemos una función muy buena **compareTo()** que te devuelve un valor Integer que si lo pones en un bucle anidado que recorra tu vector con un condicional

```
if(vector[pos].compareTo(vector[pos+1])>0)
{
  Guardamos el valor actual en una variable auxiliar
  Asignamos el valor vector[pos+1] a vector[pos]
  vector[pos] = variable auxiliar
}
```

Ref: https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-string-compareto-method-example/

Dale un par de vueltas y si aun no lo consigues vuelve a pegar tu código de lo que has probado y te ayudaremos.

Answer (score 0):

Este es un intento para eliminar un valor del array pero no lo elimina el valor aunque la sintaxis esta bien.

```
            System.out.println("ingrese que dato quiere eliminar");
            String nomeliminar = sc.next();

            for(int i=0; i<alum.length;i++) {
                if(alum[i] == nomeliminar) {
                    alum[i]=null;
                    break;
```